# Error when loading vimtutor "E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim80/tutor/tutor.vim"

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opensuse

I'm trying to run `vimtutor` on openSUSE Leap 15 1 on WSL2. I get the error `E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim80/tutor/tutor.vim`

When I run `which vim` (or `which vimtutor`) I get `/usr/bin/vim` (or `/usr/bin/vimtutor`) -- is the issue that I have multiple versions of vim installed and when I try `vimtutor` (which I understand to be a script) it can't access the correct one because of the way my `PATH` is configured? I've seen similar issues about this posted, but none that seem to deal with this specific issue as it applies to `vimtutor`.

Comment: In Debian `tutor.vim` is in a separate package `vim-runtime`. I know nothing on how SUSE/OpenSUSE split vim packages but verify they're installed.

Comment: Doesn't look like that package exists on openSUSE

Comment: Seems it must be in the very package `vim`. At least that how I read [the spec](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Leap:15.1/vim/vim.spec?expand=1).

Answer (score 0):

The vim script is part of vim-data package.

If you looked at the spec file linked here,
https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/vim/vim.spec?expand=1
on line 567, the tutor.vim is split into the vim-data package.

It's part of the

```
%files data
```

block.